# Only one CPU core is active on Fedora 16

Tags: fedora, cpu

I've upgraded from F15 to **F16** and noticed that I have a problems with hardware detection. Upon loading I can see message like

```
...
CPU#1 not responding
...
```

on the screen. It disappears and I can login then as usually. But I have **only 1 CPU** in System Monitor and it is **always loaded** by 80-100%. So my PC is very noisy. :) I've noticed also that Caps Lock indicator is always on irregardless of actual caps lock status. And the system freezes out after 5-10 minutes. :(

I've tried **clean install of F16** and the problem is the same.

My PC is **Compaq Presario CQ56-118EO** with **Intel Pentium Dual Core T4500 CPU**. I've tried to google but failed.

Is my hardware/BIOS/karma incompatible with Linux 3.x?

[dmesg output](http://pastebin.com/nbtdcKwN)

P.S. I upgraded my BIOS to the last version available at HP site dated back to April of 2011. No changes...

P.P.S. Not Foedora specific. Exactly the same situation with openSUSE 12.1

Comment: 3.x didn't actually change anything, Linus just decided it was time to call it 3.0.

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit distribution?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

Well... Seems like i found out a solution. At least it worked in my case so it's a worth try.

1. Turn off PC.
2. Disconnect the power cord.
3. Remove the battery.
4. Wait a bit.
5. Insert the battery.
6. Connect the power cord.
7. Turn on PC.

Comment: 1. I forced to do this trick EVERY start. 2. After 5 minutes it freezes anyway.